# Joi array Object validation based on root key value

Tags: javascript, node.js, joi

I have a complex scenario that I want to validate using `Joi`
here sample Joi Object Schema

```
const itemSchema = Joi.object({
    product_id: Joi.string().required(),
    quantity: Joi.number().required().min(0)
});

let objSchema = {
    items: Joi.array().items(itemSchema).required().min(1),
    item_return_flag: Joi.string().optional().valid(true, false)
};
```

depending opon `item_return_flag` key value `true` or `false`, I want to change the `items.quantity` min value requirement. When `true`, quantity will be 0 , otherwise it will be 1.

Is there anyway, to control the definition of validation of the object in an array, based on the root object in `Joi`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sample code that will switch the schema based one the parent key `item_return_flag`. Schema of the array need to switch based using `Joi.altertnatives()`

```
let itemArr = Joi.object({
    product_id: Joi.string().required(),
    quantity: Joi.number().required().min(0)
});

let itemArr2 = Joi.object({
    product_id: Joi.string().required(),
    quantity: Joi.number().required().min(1)
});

let itemSchema = Joi.alternatives()
    .when('item_return_flag', { is: true, then: Joi.array().items(itemArr).required().min(1), otherwise: Joi.array().items(itemArr2).required().min(1)}) ;

let objSchema = {
    items: itemSchema,
    item_return_flag: Joi.string().optional().valid(true, false)
};
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you could, following the [API docs](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v13.6.0/API.md#alternativeswhencondition-options), do something like this:

```
let objSchema = {
     items: Joi.array().items(Joi.object({
         product_id: Joi.string().required(),
         quantity: Joi.alternatives().when('item_return_flag', {
              is: true, then:  Joi.number().required().min(0), 
              otherwise: Joi.number().required().min(1)
         })
     })).required().min(1),
     item_return_flag:  Joi.string().optional().valid(true, false)
};
```

I'm not 100% sure that's the exact correct structure, but it's close. The `Joi.alternatives()` is provided for just such use cases.